# How to move the value of categories next to y axis of bar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I spent lots of time to solve this problem. Strangely, I thought
I can find the solution after watching how to create bar chart searched for "how to make a bar chart in Excel" and watched YouTube. But I couldn't.

I was trying to move categories next to y-axis but now all categories are inside the bar as shown in the picture.

Could you please tell me what keywords I should try and how to do this stuff?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi0zq.png]

Answer (score 1):

Please select the categories > Right click it > Format Axis > Expand **Labels** under Axis Options tab> Set **High**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!